TikZ clipping on polygons clips everything
Consider the following M(non)WE:
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{vertex} = [draw, fill, circle, thick, minimum size=0.75mm, inner sep=0]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[vertex] (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node[vertex] (B) at (1,2) {};
  \node[vertex] (C) at (3,2) {};
  \node[vertex] (D) at (4,0) {};

  \clip (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

  \draw[ultra thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A);

  \draw[thick] (A) -- (C);
  \draw[thick] (0,1) -- (4,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

One would expect that the clip command in the middle would hide all drawings outside of the quadrilateral ABCD (I did), yet it does something else, apparently hiding (almost) everything. Below are two pictures, with and without the clip command:

The lower side of the quadrilateral being hidden completely is apparently due to -- cycle command instead of -- (A), but the diagonal and the diagonal being hidden are puzzling. I remember doing essentially the same many times, so some really stupid mistake on my side must be the reason here, yet I struggle to see it. Also, what's going one with the linewidth?
Replacing the clip command with something like \clip (A) rectangle (C); works as expected.
I'm doing it with MiKTeX 2.9 distrib, both on PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX, all the packages are up to date.

Please note that \tikzstyle  is deprecated. Have a look at \tikzset instead.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I know, but as they say, "old habits die hard".

You want \clip (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) -- (D.center) -- cycle; and \draw[ultra thick] (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) -- (D.center) -- cycle;, because you want to connect coordinates and not nodes (which breaks the path in segements preventing it from being a single closed area).

You want:
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    vertex/.style = {
        draw, 
        fill, 
        circle, 
        thick, 
        minimum size=0.75mm, 
        inner sep=0
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[vertex] (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node[vertex] (B) at (1,2) {};
  \node[vertex] (C) at (3,2) {};
  \node[vertex] (D) at (4,0) {};

  \clip (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) -- (D.center) -- cycle;

  \draw[ultra thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A);

  \draw[thick] (A) -- (C);
  \draw[thick] (0,1) -- (4,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Why? Because if you say \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);, you are drawing a path consisting of two segments which won't become a single closed path if using cycle. This is because a path from a node to the next node will start and and at the border of these nodes, not at their center.
Actually, this is not the first question regarding this issue, but I am currently unable to find other similar questions on this site.
